# exercicio javascript

Tags: javascript

Boas pessoal, estou a iniciar-me em javascript e deparei-me com este exercicio.
é possivel darem um ajuda na resoluação?

Temos um utilizador muito mal criado. Queremos que ele peça por favor no final de cada pergunta. Faz uma função que acrescente ", please?" ao final de cada pergunta.

Ou seja, a utilização deste seria:

```
const phrase = makePoliteQuestion('Can you open the door?');
//phrase seria 'Can you open the door, please?'
```

Mas só se for uma pergunta!
Ou seja,

```
const phrase = makePoliteQuestion('Open the door.');
//phrase seria 'Open the door.'
```

Ajuda: 
Tentem dividir a função em várias funções pequenas! (Por exemplo, verificar se é uma questão pode ser uma função só)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente fazer um replace do `?` por `, please?`, assim isso vai colocar o por favor nas frases que tiverem interrogações

```js
function makePoliteQuestion(str) {
  return str.replace('?', ', please?');
}

console.log(makePoliteQuestion('Can you open the door?'));
//phrase seria 'Can you open the door, please?'

console.log(makePoliteQuestion('Open the door.')); 
//phrase seria 'Open the door.'

console.log(makePoliteQuestion('Can you open the door???'));
//phrase seria 'Can you open the door, please???'
```